# create a new column to show the quintile in groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Edit: I got several answers below, but as I commented at each of the answers, they seem not to work together with a `groupby` function. I often got errors such as '`TypeError: invalid type comparison`'

I want to create a new column that shows the quintile of the value columns. The sample data is shown below:

```
d = {'group1': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A','B','B','B','B','B'], 'group2': ['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b','a','b'],
     'value': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

```
group1  group2  value
A      a       1
A      b       2
A      a       3
A      b       4
A      a       5
B      b       6
B      a       7
B      b       8
B      a       9
B      b      10
```

I want the result to be

```
group1  group2  value   quintile 
A      a       1       1
A      b       2       1
A      a       3       2
A      b       4       2
A      a       5       3
B      b       6       3
B      a       7       4
B      b       8       4
B      a       9       5
B      b       10      5
```

I tried several approaches, but they don't work. For example, the following is what I tried:

```
df['quintile'] = df.groupby(['group1','group2'])['value'].quintile()
```

Comment: could you elaborate what quintiles are for you? Because df['quintile'] = df.groupby(['group1','group2'])['value'].quantile() will return the quantiles.

Comment: They will not return quantiles when combining with a groupby function. I edited my question to include a working example and errors that I got.

Answer (score 1):

I believe panda.qcut is whatn you are looking for

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10), columns=['value'])
df['quintile'] = pd.qcut(df['value'], 5, labels=False)
df

  value quintile
1   1   0
2   2   1
3   3   1
4   4   2
5   5   2
6   6   3
7   7   3
8   8   4
9   9   4
10  10   5
```

check this out for more [about (pd.qcut)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html)

Comment: Thanks, can you share an answer incorporating groupby? I tried to add groupby to your answer: df['quintile'] = pd.qcut(df.groupby(['group1','group2'])['value'], 5, labels=False), I got error: "TypeError: invalid type comparison"

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.cut(df['value'], bins=5, labels=[x for x in range(1,6)])
```

Comment: Thanks. If I added groupby function such as pd.cut(df.groupby(['group1','group2'])['value'], bins=5, labels=[x for x in range(1,6)]), I got an error: 
TypeError: invalid type comparison

Answer (score 0):

You have a parenthesis missing after groupby.
Also if you are looking for quantiles, the following works:

```
df.groupby(['group1','group2'])['value'].quantile()
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for quintile. There is no quintile function. AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'quintile'